# Showing a set is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$, equipped $X$ by giving Lebesgue measure on Borel sigma-algebra and equipped $Y$ by giving counting measure on the power set of $Y$. Define $D=\{(x,x):0\leq x\leq 1\}$ then how do we show that $D$ is measurable set in product sigma-algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D$ is closed and hence
$$
D\in \mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)=\mathcal{B}([0,1])\otimes \mathcal{B}([0,1]).
$$

Comment: Sigma-algebra in $Y$ is not Borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: No, but the product sigma-algebra obtained by equipping $Y$ with the power set is larger than this and hence...

Comment: Oho! Yeah, but why $D\in \mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)$?

Comment: $D$ is closed in $[0,1]^2$ and $\mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)$ is generated by all open (or closed) sets in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Then is it true that $\int_{X}(\int_{Y}\chi_{D}(x,y)d\mu)d\lambda=1$ and the other way is $\int_{Y}(\int_{X}\chi_{D}(x,y)d\lambda)d\mu=0$? What is $\int_{X\times{Y}}\chi_{D}(x,y)d(\lambda\times{\mu)}$?

Comment: Yes. You tell me. What is $\lambda\times \mu$? Since $\mu$ isn't $\sigma$-finite, the product measure is not unique.

Comment: $\lambda\times{\mu}$ is just the product measure.

Comment: Which is not uniquely defined since $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite and hence the integral with respect to $\lambda\times \mu$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: I don't understand why do we need $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) for example.

Comment: But it should be $\lambda\times{\mu}(D)$, right? And since $D$ is measurable then $\lambda\times{\mu}(D)$ should be some number from $0$ to $\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that $(\lambda\times\mu)(D)$ isn't uniquely defined c.f. my previous comments. I think you need to revisit the section in your book/notes about product measure. I'm sure that somewhere in there it says that $\sigma$-finiteness is needed in order for the product measure to uniquely extend.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $D$ is a graph of a non-negative measurable function mapping from $Y$ to $X$.